# Why is my LLDB debugger in Android Studio skipping all breakpoints?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface, android-studio-2.2

I've successfully migrated my android project to Android Studio 2.2.3, with all of the JNI libs. I've read about the LLDB debugger which can be used to debug native code and I loved the idea.
I have created some breakpoints in my C code, but the LLDB goes over them and does not stop.
Same thing happens with Java breakpoints. I have it set to Auto and the LLDB tickbox is checked, but it still goes over everything.
If I use the regular debugger the Java breakpoints work fine.

I am not sure what kind of information could I provide to help you with identifying the issue.

Here's my build.gradle config:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs {
                srcDirs = ['jni/db', 'jni/minizip', 'jni/roxml']
            }

        }
    }


    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the `Symbol Directories` in `Run/Debug Configurations`.

The location is:
`<project_dir>/<module_dir>/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local`

I was worried these are `release` but it seems to work fine.

At least it worked until my Android Studio C/C++ integration broke...